# What causes the error 'unknown option "pyimage1"' while I'm trying to load image onto canvas with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I've been trying to use tkinter for creating GUI with Python, today I decided to use images in my GUI, but while using Canvas from tkinter I ran into this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      

   File "C:\Users\37063\Desktop\pomodoro\main.py", line 25, in <module>
        canvas.create_image((100, 112), image_canvas)
   File "C:\Users\37063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2786, in create_image
        return self._create('image', args, kw)
   File "C:\Users\37063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2772, in _create
        return self.tk.getint(self.tk.call(
    _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "pyimage1" .
```

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("Gui test")
canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=224)
image_canvas = PhotoImage(file='ygo.gif')
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_image((100, 112), image_canvas)

window.mainloop()
```

As I googled the error I saw that sometime it is solved by changing your image format, I tried .png, .jpeg, .gif and none of them seem to work for me. Thank you for your advise in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must supply the image as the value of the keyword argument `image`:

```
canvas.create_image((100, 112), image=image_canvas)
#                               ^^^^^^
```